# Edit link and joint names in the editor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello list,

Is it possible to initial set joint and link names or edit them afterwards in the editor?
Or should that be done in the sdf-file directly?

I want to create a complex robot in the editor and than later convert it into a urdf to use it from ROS.
During this development I would like more meaningful names for the links and joints.

Thanks in advance,
Sietse Achterop

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20598/edit-link-and-joint-names-in-the-editor/) by [Sietse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6373/sietse/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can edit the joint name in the 'joint inspector' after you right click on the selected part. You can't rename the links, though.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2018-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6373/sietse/) on 2018-10-05**:
Thanks. It is a pity that there seems no work ongoing in better integrating urdf and sdf.